# How can i extend Joomla session if user still active on client javascript application in joomla?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, joomla

I faced this problem: JS(jquery) application is integrated to joomla. How can i know user still active on JS application and if user is active how can i extend joomla session timeout?

Answer (score 0):

Do an Ajax call once in a while which just updates the session time on the server. You can use window.setInterval() in JS to schedule this.

Comment: Thank you Emil, Ajax call which updates session time of joomla ?

Comment: Every time a user calls a page from your site the session time is reset. So in ajax just call any arbitrary page that doesn't have to return anything and session time will be reset.